# Export json on the appropriate location on the server via js?

Tags: json, server, export

It's possible to Export json on the appropriate location on the server via js? I can't use node, only javaScript with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript run in browsers is designed in such a way as to work on the client's computer or communicate with servers using HTTP and web sockets. The idea of ​​these technologies is client-server communication. If you really can not use NodeJS to write the right server, maybe you should consider whether to use other technologies? For example Go, PHP, Ruby, Python etc. However, if it is not possible to start a server that will perform the task you are talking about, unfortunately it is rather impossible